# split a filename and join chunks to directory structure

Tags: .net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I want to split a requested url filename chunks of up to 2 characters and then rewrite to a directory structure:

Input (line-by-line):

```
a.txt
ba.txt
cba.txt
dcba.txt
edcba.txt
fedcba.txt
gfedcba.txt
hgfedcba.txt
```

Desired Output:

```
a/file.txt
ba/file.txt
c/ba/file.txt
dc/ba/file.txt
e/dc/ba/file.txt
fe/dc/ba/file.txt
g/ef/dc/ba/file.txt
hg/ef/dc/ba/file.txt
```

Achived output (with regex following):

```
///a/file.txt
///ba/file.txt
//c/ba/file.txt
//dc/ba/file.txt
/e/dc/ba/file.txt
/fe/dc/ba/file.txt
g/fe/dc/ba/file.txt
hg/fe/dc/ba/file.txt
```

RegEx:

```
([a-z]{1,2}?)??([a-z]{1,2}?)??([a-z]{1,2}?)??([a-z]{1,2})??\.txt
```

Replacement:

```
$1/$2/$3/$4/file.txt
```

I found no way to repeat a match and capture each iteration.

Unfortunately even if a match $1 - $3 is not found a slash will be written by this replacement text.

Comment: changed question - made it more clear, that i don't want to match the same character twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way using .NET [Group.Captures Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx)

LinqPad snippet:

```
string inputUrl= "/gfedcba.txt";
string pattern = @"/([a-z]{1,2})+\.txt";
string rewrittenUrl = inputUrl;

Match match = Regex.Match(inputUrl, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

if(match.Success){
    var captures = match.Groups[1].Captures;
    rewrittenUrl="";
    for(int i = captures.Count; i > 0; i--) {
        rewrittenUrl += "/" + captures[i-1].Value;
    }
    rewrittenUrl += ".txt";
}

"inputUrl:".Dump();
inputUrl.Dump();
"rewrittenUrl:".Dump();
rewrittenUrl.Dump();
```

LinqPad output:

> inputUrl:
>
> /gfedcba.txt
>
> rewrittenUrl:
>
> /g/fe/dc/ba.txt

now i'm going to write an [custom IIS Url Rewrite Provider](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/803/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not entirely clear. I have given it a go with the assumption that you want to match the same character twice if possible, otherwise just once. If thats not the case the pattern becomes a bit more complicated, but here's an example of how you can do it: http://regex101.com/r/nG4tZ9

`/^|\G(([a-z])\2?)/gm`

Use this as replacement: `\1/`

This will procude the following result:

```
/a/.txt
/aa/.txt
/b/aa/.txt
/bb/aa/.txt
/c/bb/aa/.txt
/cc/bb/aa/.txt
/d/cc/bb/aa/.txt
/dd/cc/bb/aa/.txt
```

I am unsure of how to inject the `file.txt` part in any smooth way, I'm not entirely sure its possible without a proper language to do it in.

I don't recommend you do anything beyond what I have presented with regular expressions. I would write a small function for it instead.

Seeing as this is url-rewriting, I am not sure there are any good solutions out there to be frank. You could try to handle this with your own script files, and then just use headers to redirect from there. I'm no expert, I'm sure someone has a better solution.

Good luck.